# Problema con shell script en Mac (dialogos osascript)

Tags: shell, macos, diálogo

Estoy creando un script para eliminar algunos archivos (mi finalidad es aprender a utilizar los dialogos y ejecutar algunas tareas), lo fui formando en base a ejemplos en la red, los dialogos funcionan bien, excepto cuando quiero que ejecute los comandos `sudo`, me dice:

> syntax error: Se esperaba final de línea pero se encontró identificador. (-2741)

Al principio intente crear una funcion para llamarla pero tampoco funciono, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<EOT
 app "System Events"
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "Deseas eliminar MySQL?" buttons {"Si", "No"} default button 2)
#display dialog "You selected " & answer
if answer = "No" then
display dialog "Cancelado" buttons {"Aceptar"}
else
if (answer = "Si")then
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysql.plist
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.st.plist
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "Se ha eliminado MySQL, es necesario reiniciar.\nDeseas reiniciar ahora?" buttons {"Si","Reiniciar mas tarde"}default button 2)
end if
end if
return  -- Suppress result
end
EOT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lanzar osascript como sudo desde el principio en lugar de utilizar sudo en cada comando y utilizar `do shell script "código"` poniendo una ";" para separar cada comando:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo osascript <<EOT
 app "System Events"
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "Deseas eliminar MySQL?" buttons {"Si", "No"} default button 2)
#display dialog "You selected " & answer
if (answer = "No") then
display dialog "Cancelado" buttons {"Aceptar"}
else
if (answer = "Si")then
do shell script "sudo rm /usr/local/mysql;
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql;
rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*;
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist;
rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM;
rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*;
rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*;
rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*;
rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*;
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysql.plist;
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.st.plist;"

set answer2 to the button returned of (display dialog "Se ha eliminado MySQL, es necesario reiniciar.\nDeseas reiniciar ahora?" buttons {"Si","Reiniciar mas tarde"}default button 2)
if (answer2 = "Si")then
tell app "System Events" to restart

end if
end if
return  -- Suppress result
end
EOT
```